# What is the parameter 'k' in multiple feedback filter design?

Tags: filter, active-filter

In this [tutorial from Analog](https://www.analog.com/media/ru/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-220.pdf) devices, what is 'k'?  The unit seems to be 1/ohm. Is it some arbitrary number to help with finding the R and C values?

Comment: The paper is a cookbook. They created k because it was a common term in their equations and you'd only need to calculate it with your calculator just once this way making the remaining calculations easier. You could search out meaning for it, and there usually is some to be found when you look deeply enough. But I don't think any was intended by the author except to help out someone with a calculator in their hands.

Comment: That's what I thought, Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> *In this tutorial from Analog devices, what is 'k'?*

The 24th instance of k is: -

$$k = 2 π F_0 C5$$

On page 2. Also on page 2 is suggests k is: -

$$k = 2 π F_0 C1$$

But this is for a different circuit.

CTRL-F for "find" then enter "k"

Comment: OK who is the wise guy with the down vote?

Comment: It wasn't me. I generally don't mark anyone down no matter what, so you can almost assume it is never me. But it's obvious from the questioner that they already know where **k** is located in the paper. They even properly computed the units (siemens or inverse-Ohms.) So that pretty much guarantees that they read the definitions in the paper. Which means they can find them. Etc. Probably someone marked you down for misunderstanding that fact.

Comment: Yeah I never thought it was anyone in particular. I just answered the question as it came to me.

Comment: Understood. If someone marks you down I think they should let you know they did and why. That way, you can repair the issue (if it is a valid complaint, of course.)